# Sending mod key over VNC

Tags: vnc, xmonad, dwm

I'm running dwm on my local machine and I'm trying to control a machine running xmonad over VNC. They both use the same mod key because they're both my machines. How can I send the mod key to the remote machine so I can actually change workspaces?

My VNC client is tightvnc.

Comment: XMonad.Actions.KeyRemap http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Actions-KeyRemap.html might be useful

Comment: Actually, I would imagine this functionality could be supported by the VNC client itself. Virtualbox client works in this manner.